# How to show % values with decimals in LWC standard datatable

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a `Discount__c` custom field with data type `Percent(15, 3)` and it has a values of `1.219%`

I am trying to fetch and display the value `1.219%` in standard datatable under "`DISCOUNT`" column.

```
{ label: 'DISCOUNT', fieldName: 'Discount__c', type: 'percent', cellAttributes: {alignment: 'center'}}
```

But my datatable [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/iBfK8QPn5/2/edit) displaying column value as `122%` instead of `1.219%`, which is multiplying the value with `100` and rounding the value.

If i give `type: 'number'` in `JS` my datatable [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/iBfK8QPn5/2/edit) is displaying correct value like `1.219` but i want to display the `%` symbol for each value in the "`DISCOUNT`" column along with `3` decimals like `1.219%`.

**Playground link :-** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/iBfK8QPn5/2/edit

HTML

```
    <template>
        <lightning-datatable
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            key-field="id">
        </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
```

JS Code

```
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

    const columns = [
         {label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'},
         {label: 'DISCOUNT', fieldName: 'discount__c', type: 'percent', 
               cellAttributes:{ alignment: 'center'}},
         {label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', 
               cellAttributes:{ alignment: 'center'}, typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'EUR', 
               alignment: 'center'}},];

    const data = [{
                    id: 'a',
                    opportunityName: 'Cloudhub',
                    discount__c: 1.219,
                    amount: 25000

                },
                {
                    id: 'b',
                    opportunityName: 'Quip',
                    discount__c: 1.219,
                    amount: 740000
                }];

    export default class DatatableExample extends LightningElement {
         data = data;
         columns = columns;
    }
```

He is the sample playground code link [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/iBfK8QPn5/2/edit)

Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Percentage fields are always stored as a fraction of 1. "Per cent" literally means "one part per hundred", so 1% is actually 0.01. Storing the data this way simplifies calculations using the value (try a formula field on Opportunities `Amount * Probability`, you'll see what I mean).

If you have a value of 1.219%, it should be downloaded to the client as 0.01219. The value 1.219 means 121.9% in a percentage format. If not, there's something wrong with how you're retrieving the value. You should add a typeAttributes of maximumFractionDigits set to at least 3, in order to show all the fraction digits. I've updated your [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/iBfK8QPn5/3/edit) for you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not like to change data so I add the datatable type percent-fixed.

Solution I have done:
import percentfixed from './percentfixed.html';

```
export default class MyDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        percentfixed : {
            template : percentfixed,
        } 
    }
}
```

Then:
percentFixed.html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-formatted-number value={value} format-style="percent-fixed" maximum-fraction-digits="2"></lightning-formatted-number>
</template>
```

then you can use you new datatable component with new type percentFixed on column.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think is dividing the table field(discount) value per 100.

```
const data = [{
        id: 'a',
        opportunityName: 'Cloudhub',
        discount__c: 1.219/100,
        amount: 25000

    },
    {
        id: 'b',
        opportunityName: 'Quip',
        discount__c: 1.219/100,
        amount: 740000
    }];
    console.log(data);
```

And then use type percent.
Please let me know.